# Table partition by following order by date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table as below, need to get the output

```
ID   Data From        To  
1    aa    2015-01-01  2015-01-05
1    aa    2015-01-05  2015-01-09
1    aa    2015-01-09  2015-01-15
1    bb    2015-01-15  2015-01-20
1    aa    2015-01-01  2015-01-05
1    aa    2015-01-05  2015-01-11
2    aa    2015-01-06  2015-01-10
```

expected output will be

```
1    a    2015-01-01  2015-01-15
1    b    2015-01-15  2015-01-20
1    a    2015-01-01  2015-01-11
2    a    2015-01-06  2015-01-10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: formatted table ID   Data From        To  
1    aa    2015-01-01  2015-01-05

1    aa    2015-01-05  2015-01-09

1    aa    2015-01-09  2015-01-15

1    bb    2015-01-15  2015-01-20

1    aa    2015-01-01  2015-01-05

1    aa    2015-01-05  2015-01-11

2    aa    2015-01-06  2015-01-10


expected output will be

ID      Data      From         To  
1        a     2015-01-01   2015-01-15

1        b      2015-01-15   2015-01-20

1        a      2015-01-01   2015-01-11

2        a      2015-01-06  2015-01-10

Comment: @ RDBMS system  it combines OLAP and OLTP

Comment: Sql Server or Oracle or Postgres or Mysql or DB2,...

Comment: SQL server         yes,

Comment: Do have any other column to define the order ?

Comment: No.. these are the fields and the order is based on Time

Comment: 1st and 5th record is identical how will you find the order

Comment: Anyone can help this..?

Comment: You didn't answer to my previous question. Do you have any identity column ?

Comment: ID and Data are the columns to be in order. These two columns need to be in order keeping  from date is in ascending order.